# Can one single torrent use more than one connection to download

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I have downloaded an application called utorrent. I have three separate adsl connections running simultaneously on the same computer. Now can the application like utorrent have a single torrent (say torrent a) to use the total bandwidth of all connections. Will they cause any problems in downloads like clashes or redundancy or requesting a piece more than one time. If not will two or more active torrent at the simultaneously using the three connections solve this issue. Thought?

Comment: If you have something to add you should edit your [existing question](http://superuser.com/questions/909307/can-i-bridge-3-internet-connections-in-windows-8) instead of creating a new one. You can take a look at http://speedify.com BTW.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a decentralized protocol like [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent) you are using a P2P protocol that doesn't use a server to get the data, so assuming that you are not allowed to make a default route cause you don't know the list of peers who can share that data with you from the beginning, and assuming you have 3 ADSL Connections running in your PC you have 3 PPPoE Miniports running at once so for your Application you are only 1 host,
regardless of how many active connections you have.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing) are some deep explanation about routing for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your local Bittorrent peer knows what pieces it has, so it won't be asking for a single piece more than once.

As far as the application using all three connections ...

Your system's TCP/IP stack knows the subnet mask (typically statically assigned or given to it via DHCP) of any LAN it's connected to.  It can be connected to more than one, for example, your wired connection may be on one subnet and your WLAN may be on another.

So if it wants to send something to a system on a subnet, it knows which NIC to send it out on.  This works for *directly connected subnets only*.

If NIC #1 on your system has IP is 192.168.2.5 and your subnet mask is 255.255.2.0, and you send something to 192.168.2.8, it knows (because of the subnet mask) to send it out of NIC #1.

Hosts available only through the Internet are by definition not on any subnet your system might be connected to.  So, what your system does is use the *default gateway*, if one is specified.  The default gateway would be the IP of your router or your ISP's upstream router.

If you have more than one default gateway, your system might:

- stick to the first one that works
- use one and "failover" to another one if that goes down
- round robin between them.

I am really unsure of what Windows does, and you might want to read about [this warning about disjoint networks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/159168) which I believe only applies if it's connected to a private IP range like 192.168.X.X, 10.X.X.X.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround:
Install a virtual machine on your pc and set its network gateway to be the second gateway you have.
Install the torrent software on the virtual machine as well. Download your torrents in your virtual machine and in your host.
In your host, add the ip of your virtual machine in the peers list.
In your virtual machine, add the ip of your host in the peers list.
I have tried it and my download speed peeked to almost the speed of both connections combined.